# undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "Shape::get_area()", referenced from: votable for shape in shape.o

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, polymorphism, linker-errors

Hi I'm pretty sure that my issue is something stupid but I cannot figure out what it is for the life of me. I have this homework assignment which is basically meant to reinforce what we have learned about polymorphism in class (this is C++ by the way). The basis of the program is a class called shape which is the parent for circle, triangle and rectangle.

Im getting a linker error with the pure virtual method get_area() which is meant to be defined in the child classes. I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't compile, I haven't even made the main method to make use of it yet and its essentially a prototype method it shouldn't link to anything right?

Anyway here is the code for the shape.h file:

```
#ifndef Assign8_Shape_h
#define Assign8_Shape_h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;

class Shape{

private:
    string color;

public:
    Shape(const string& n_color);
    virtual ~Shape ();
    void print();
    virtual double get_area() = 0;

};

#endif
```

And then here is the Shape.cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace::std;

Shape::Shape(const string& n_color) {
    color = n_color;
}

Shape::~Shape (){

}

void Shape::print() {
    cout << color;
}
```

and here is an example of the how the problematic method is overwritten in Circle.h:

```
#ifndef __Assign8__Circle__
#define __Assign8__Circle__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace::std;


class Circle : public Shape
{

public:
    Circle(const string& n_color, int n_radius);
    void print();
    double get_area();



private:
    int radius;

};
```

and then in Circle.cpp:

```
#include "Circle.h"


using namespace::std;

Circle::Circle(const string& n_color, int n_radius) : Shape(n_color) {
    radius = n_radius;
}

void Circle::print(){
    Shape::print();
    cout  << ", radius " << radius << " area " << get_area();
}

double Circle::get_area() {
    double pi = 3.14159265359;

    return pi * (radius * radius);
}
```

and then here is the full body of the error:

```
Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Products/Debug/Assign8 normal x86_64
    cd /Users/username/Documents/NIU/CSCI241/Assign8
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Utilities/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Utilities/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Intermediates/Assign8.build/Debug/Assign8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Assign8.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Intermediates/Assign8.build/Debug/Assign8.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Assign8_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CSCI241-dhkihmradodwdkerbhwjkshakexl/Build/Products/Debug/Assign8

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Shape::get_area()", referenced from:
      vtable for Shape in Shape.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: One thing (unrelated to your stated problem): Shape::print is not declared virtual, did you intend print to be polymorphic also?

Comment: Re-run the compilation with the -v option, as suggested by the error message. Otherwise it is hard to see what's being included in the linking.

Comment: Don't do `using namespace std;` and `#include <stdio.h>` in the header. You don't need iostream in header either.

Comment: @harmic - Do you know how I use the -v option in Xcode? I can't find a spot to add flags in the options

Comment: @MattMcNabb - where shouldn't I do "using namespace std;" and so far as I see i do include <stdio.h> everywhere but in Circle.ccp, honestly I wasn't sure if I needed it, wouldn't it be included because it is included in the header?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with XCode.

Comment: Try to write as few includes as possible in header files, as it forces anyone that includes your header to also have those includes . `using namespace std` should only go in the cpp files.

Comment: are you actually on a x86_64 machine?

Comment: Try a clean rebuild. Especially if you have recently changed a function from concrete to pure virtual.

Comment: Im using a mid 2010 17" mac running OSX 10.9.5, I'd assume it is 64 bit?

Comment: So I just removed '#include <iostream>' as @MattMcNabb suggested, found I needed it for cout, put it back and it compiled. Im going to go die of shame now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles without problems on Ubuntu with g++ version 4.8.2:

```
$ g++ -o c Circle.cpp Shape.cpp
$ ./c
area=28.274334

int main()
{ 
  Circle c ("white", 3);
  printf("area=%lf\n", c.get_area());
  return 0;
}
```

You omitted an #endif at the end of Circle.h, and shape.h should be named Shape.h.
But how are you compiling and linking the code? Could it be you are not having all
pieces of the program in the process?

Comment: The missing endif was a copy error on my part. Im compiling using Xcode on my mac, I'm not sure which versions I'm using, but they are the default ones. This wouldn't be the first time my mac has caused me "unique" problems... Thanks for responding though I guess I'll write the main program and hope it compiles on the unix system tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The missing vtable bit in the message suggests `Shape.cpp` is not being linked. Since you are working with an IDE which configures this on your behalf when a source is compiled -- `Shape.cpp` is likely not being compiled.